# How to make a something required AND use a regular expression attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a viewmodel that works fine EXCEPT if the person enters nothing and hits submit, then i get a db error because the column doesn't except nulls.

I am doing

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
```

How can I make this Email field use a RegularExpression AND a required attribute at the same time?

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^......$", ErrorMessageType = ..., ErrorMessageResourceName = ...]
    public string Email {get;set;}

    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you set in the RequiredAttribute 'AllowEmptyStrings = false'?

Comment: Just add the `[Required]` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`RequiredAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
```

Now, if there isn't a value it will fail and if there is one the [`RegularExpressionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will validate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add many validation attributes like this :

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email address is mandatory")]
[RegularExpression(@"^......$", ErrorMessageType = ..., ErrorMessageResourceName = ...]
public string Email {get;set;}
```